# Predict the required number of preallocated nodes in a kD-Tree

Tags: c++, geometry, computer-science, computational-geometry, kdtree

I'm implementing a dynamic **kD-Tree in array representation** (storing the nodes in std::vector) in breadth-first fashion. Each `i`-th non-leaf node have a left child at `(i<<1)+1` and a right child at `(i<<1)+2`. It would support incremental insertion of points and collection of points.
However I'm facing problem determining the required number of possible nodes to incrementally preallocate space.

I've found a [formula on the web](http://programmizm.sourceforge.net/blog/2011/a-practical-implementation-of-kd-trees), which seems to be wrong:

> N = min(m − 1, 2n − ½m − 1),
>
> where m is the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to n, the
>   number of points.

My implementation of the formula is the following:

```
size_t required(size_t n)
{
    size_t m = nextPowerOf2(n);
    return min(m - 1, (n<<1) - (m>>1) - 1);
}
```

*function nextPowerOf2 returns a power of 2 largest or equal to n*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should first try to share your thoughts with the blog's writer.

Comment: Have you tried with a small number of points to see where the error is? what was the error, not enough pre-allocated objects? Would you mind to put actual values.. e.g.: I tried with `X` points... the `m` calculate was `Y`, and `required` return the value `Z`.. but in the end I needed `W` nodes

Comment: since the question is about the number of required nodes, yes, the error is the not enough preallocated nodes, which leads to segfault. i tested the algorithm with actual values, it is working, however running out of the storage.

Answer (score 1):

Each node of a kd-tree divides the space into two spaces. Hence, the number of nodes in the kd-tree depends on how you perform this division:

1) If you divide them in the midpoint of the space (that is, if the space is from x1 to x2, you divide the space with the x3=(x1+x2)/2 line), then:
i) Each point will be allocated its own node, and
ii) Each intermediate node will be empty.

In this case, the number of nodes will depend on how large the coordinates of the points are. If the coordinates are bounded by |X|, then the total number of nodes in the kd-tree should be slightly less than log |X| * n (more precisely, around log |X| * n - n log n + 2n) in the worst case. To see this, consider the following way to add the points: you add multiple collections, each collection has two extremely nearby points located at random. For each pair of point, the tree will need to continuously divide the space log |X| times, and if log |X| is significantly larger than log n, creating log |X| intermediate nodes in the process.

2) If you divide them by using a point as a dividing line, then each node (including the intermediate nodes) will contain a point. Thus, the total number of nodes is simply n. However, note that using a point to divide the space may yield to a very bad performance if the points are not given in a random order (for example, if the points are given in an ascending order of X, the depth of the tree would be O(n). For comparison, the depth of the tree in (1) is at most O(log |X|) ).

Comment: In your case 2, you assume that the kd-tree divides the pointset by the round-robin fashion axis alternating rule, which could lead to inefficiency as you stated. However this behaviour is only the effect of the alternating rule, but not the "divide them by using a point as a dividing line" technique. I use the cut longest edge rule (subdivide the pointset by the largest dimension of their axis-aligned bounding box) for subdivision which is free from this behaviour.

Comment: Furthermore, it is true that the actual number of nodes is equal to the number of points. However keep mind, that the kD-Tree is in array representation in breadth-first fashion. Each i-th node have a left child at (i<<1)+1 and a right child at (i<<1)+2. So the nodes don't require to explicitly store their left/right children. This representation is cache-friendly, unlike a linked-list one. In this particular case you need to preallocate more space than you actually needed because theoretically each node could have a left and/or right child on i+1 and i+2, which you can't predict.

Comment: @plasmacel Right, which I forgot. In this case, you most likely won't be able to use case 1, since the memory required would now be O(|X|). Btw, if you use the longest edge rule, I assume you're dividing the space by their midpoint? In which case, the things I said on case 1 holds. If you sitll use case 2 (use a point to divide the space on their longest axis), then the points on case 2 still hold, namely if the points are inserted in the worst possible case, the depth of the tree is O(N), which requires 2^N memory.